# Anticommutative operad

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, operads

Let $(C, \otimes, 1)$ be a additive symmetric monoidal category with internal hom (well, lets think about $\mathrm{Mod}_R$ with $R$ a commutative ring), I am trying to figure out what would be the anticommutative operad in $C$. By that I mean: an operad $P$ such that $P-$algebras are the skew-commutative monoids in $C$.

**My try:**

Take $\mathcal{A}lt(n) = 1 \circlearrowright S_n$ with the signal representation. This seens natural just because the Schur functor would be something like an antisymmetrization

\begin{align*}
S_{\mathcal{A}lt}(A) 
= \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 1 \square_{S_n} A^{\square n}
\simeq \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathrm{coeq}_{g \in S_n} \left( \mathrm{sng}(g) g:  A^{\square n} \to A^{\square n} \right)
\end{align*}

Now the unit map $1 \to P(1)=1$ seems to be just identity map, fine. But what about multiplication map $\mu(m; i_1, \cdots, i_m): \mathcal{A}lt(m) \otimes \mathcal{A}lt(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{A}lt(i_m) \to \mathcal{A}lt(i_1 + \cdots + i_m)$  ? Well, we have a natural isomorphism $1^{m} \otimes 1^{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes 1^{i_m} \simeq 1$, I would like to use this map probably with a sign that depends on $m, i_1, \cdots, i_m$. Operad axioms give me restrictions to that sign:

1. Equivariance axiom gives:
   \begin{align}
   \mathrm{sng}(\sigma) \mu(m; i_1, \cdots, i_m) = \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma_{i_1, \cdots, i_m}) \mu(m; i_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, \cdots, i_{\sigma^{-1}(m)})
   \end{align}
   where $\sigma \in S_m$ and $\sigma_{i_1, \cdots, i_m} \in S_{i_1 + \cdots + i_m}$ is a block permutation
2. Associativity gives:
   \begin{align}
   \mu(m; j_1, \cdots, j_m) \mu(i_1; j_{1,1}, \cdots, j_{1, i_1}) \cdots \mu(i_m; j_{m,1}, \cdots, j_{m, i_m})
   = \mu(i; j_{1,1}, \cdots, j_{m, i_m}) \mu (m; i_1, \cdots, i_m)
   \end{align}
   where $i = \sum_k i_k$, $j_l = \sum_k j_{l, k}$ and $j = \sum_l j_l$.
3. Unity gives:
   \begin{align}
   \mu(1; n) = \mathrm{id}
   \quad \quad \quad \quad
   \mu(n; 1, \cdots, 1) = \mathrm{id}
   \end{align}

Maybe equation (2) gives me some recursion? I really don't know. It seems I can't just put $\mu(\cdots)$ to be the natural isomorphism because of equation (1).

Well, with all that, a $\mathcal{A}lt-$algebra would be $A\in C$ with morphisms $\gamma(m): \mathcal{A}lt(m) \otimes A^{\otimes m} \simeq A^{\otimes m} \to A$ such that

i. Equivariance: Let $g \in S_m$ action on $A^{\otimes m}$ by permutation of factors, then
\begin{align}
\gamma(m) g = \mathrm{sgn}(g)  \gamma(m)
\end{align}
Nice, it is what i want.

ii. Associativity:
\begin{align}
\gamma(m) (\gamma(i_1) \otimes \cdots \otimes \gamma(i_m) ) 
= \mu(m; i_1, \cdots, i_m) \gamma(i_1 + \cdots + i_m)
\end{align}
It seems really weird to be that sign over there.

iii. Unity: $m(1): 1 \times A  \to A$ is just the natural isomorphism. Ok.

**Problem:**

Well, equation (ii) don't make any sense to me unless all those $\mu(\cdots)$ are the natural isomorphisms, but I can't do that. What is going on here? Maybe if I understand better this block permutation sign things will go easier.

Comment: Have you tried $C=\mathbb{Z}$ or $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$?